# How to pass arguments for get method with urllib?

Tags: python, urllib

The response web page is as below when to slect **title** and input **wordpress**.

[image]

Here is my python code to pass arguments for get method with python3.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
url = 'http://www.it-ebooks.info/'
values = {'q': 'wordpress','type': 'title'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode(encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0' }
request = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=data,headers=headers,method='GET')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
buff = response.read()
html = buff.decode("utf8")
print(html)
```

I can't get the desired output web page.
How  to pass arguments for get method with urllib in my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `data` kwarg of `urllib.request.Request` is only used for POST requests as it modifies the request's body.

GET requests simply use URL parameters, so you should append these to the url:

```
params = '?q=wordpress&type=title'
url = 'http://www.it-ebooks.info/search/{}'.format(params)
```

You can of course take the time and generalize this into a generic function.

Answer (score 0):

is better if you use the library called requests

[image]

```
import requests


headers = {
    'DNT': '1',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'http://www.it-ebooks.info/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

r = requests.get('http://www.it-ebooks.info/search/?q=wordpress&type=title', headers=headers)

print r.content
```